# linux send call with flag MSG_DONTWAIT

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

On a blocking socket, if I set the flag `MSG_DONTWAIT` on a per call basis, will it effect the socket as a whole as in will the socket now behave like a non-blocking socket since this call is made with this flag?

I mean will the `recv` on the blocking socket starts behaving like a non-blocking `recv`?

Or will the effects of this flag will only last for the requested single send call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flags supplied to `sendmsg()` will affect the `sendmsg()` call only.

Comment: here I am using send() call not sendmsg(), is the behavior same?

Comment: @Medicine Of course. They are flags to the call. If you want to permanently affect the socket you use `setsockopt()`.